# Merge "map" and "maps" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I just discovered we have [map](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) (x13) and [maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) (x7) tags. Though it looks like the latter mainly deals with "map applications" (mostly Google Maps), while the former is used for "map material", I'd suggest to...

1. re-tag all "Google Maps" related questions to [google-maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) (another existing tag) if they are not referring to the map material but to the app only
2. merge `maps` with  `map`
3. optionally make the empty one a synonym to the other

Comment: Item #1 doesn't need a moderator. Go for it.

Comment: OK, done that. Still left are some double-tagged ones where I was not sure whether to remove the map/maps tag or not (i.e. the question addressed both, the app and the material). Those should solve on merge now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) is now the master and [map](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) is a synonym.